# why am I getting property of undefined in this vue.js example

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My vue dev tools and unittests are being flooded with:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'time_start' of undefined"
Cannot read property 'time_start' of undefined
```

After looking at some other posts, I'm guessing the reason for this error is related to the use of the fat arrow function?  That's the only thing I can come up with.  What's strange is that despite all these errors, the actual component itself renders fine with the expected time_start.

```
  created() {
    this.JobExecEndpoint =
      process.env.VUE_APP_TEST_URL +
      "/api/v2/tool=" +
      this.$route.params.tool +
      "&job=" +
      this.$route.params.job +
      "&id=" +
      this.$route.params.id;
    fetch(this.JobExecEndpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => {
        this.cleanStartTime = moment(body[0].time_start);
        this.cleanEndTime = moment(body[0].time_end);
        this.cleanDuration = this.calculateDuration(
          this.cleanStartTime,
          this.cleanEndTime
        );
        this.job_execs.push({
          name: body[0].job.name,
          build_id: body[0].id,
          env: body[0].job.env,
          time_start: this.cleanStartTime.format("LLL"),
          time_end: this.cleanEndTime.format("LLL"),
          duration: this.cleanDuration,
          status: body[0].status.name,
          job: body[0].job,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error Fetching:", this.JobExecEndpoint, err);
        return { failure: this.JobExecEndpoint, reason: err };
      });
  }


<template>
  <div class="overview">
    <h3>Overview</h3>
    <table :style="overviewStyle">
      <tr>
        <td :style="tdStyle">Start Time</td>
        <td :style="tdStyle">{{ job_execs[0].time_start }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </table>
</template>
```

Cannot read property 'time_start' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You're sending off an asynchronous request and the template is relying on this information to already exist. The component "looks fine" but for a split second it didn't have any real data to render (job_execs was still waiting for data when this attempted to render).

You can fix this by adding in a v-if statement to your  tag like so:

```
<td v-if:"job_execs" :style="tdStyle">{{ job_execs[0].time_start }}</td>
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I will give this a shot, but that is why I put that logic in the created hook, I figured that would make the data available before the template is rendered.  I guess that is not the case.

Comment: One thing to remember about async calls is that they can take an indefinite amount of time to complete. So the created() hook the right place for your API call, but it could (theoretically) take several seconds or more than a minute to complete so all the other code is going to run while it waits, including the rendering. I've run into this a couple times recently myself :-)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error