# How to convert my fat arrow function to a "normal" function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to convert this to a normal js function without the "fat arrow".

I want body => to be a normal function.

How do I write that?

snippet from code

```
fetch(this.JobExecEndpoint)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(body => {
    this.cleanStartTime = moment(body[0].time_start);
    this.cleanEndTime = moment(body[0].time_end);
    this.cleanDuration = this.calculateDuration(
      this.cleanStartTime,
      this.cleanEndTime
    );
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: How do you think you might do it? Have you tried anything? Also, your example code is missing a closing bracket and parenthesis.

Comment: `.then(function(body) { /* Your code here */ })`

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I believe the fat arrow function might be causing the issue that I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840300/why-am-i-getting-property-of-undefined-in-this-vue-js-example/56840535#56840535

Comment: @benjaminadon I don't think so.

Comment: yea that didnt fix it

Comment: browsers that don't support arrow functions (IE) also don't support fetch, so polyfill might be needed for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Hold a reference to "this" object inside a variable else you won't be able to access it using the "this" inside the callback function

var that = this; 

fetch(this.JobExecEndpoint).then(function(response)
{
     return response.json();
})
.then(function(body)
{
    that.cleanStartTime = moment(body[0].time_start);
    that.cleanEndTime   = moment(body[0].time_end);
    that.cleanDuration  = that.calculateDuration (
        that.cleanStartTime,
        that.cleanEndTime
    );
});
```

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any question :)

Comment: What's the point of `var that = this` when you can just do `function(body){}.bind(this)`?

Comment: You can do that as well. The syntax will just change a little bit. That's total up to you. If you use this method then you will need to use `.bind(this)` on each of the `.then()` function where was `var that = this` relieves you from this problem and you can continue chaining as long as you like :)

Comment: @meyi Using `bind()` ends up being considerably slower execution. At least it did the last time I ran a performance test on it; it could have changed. Thus, if you can avoid using `.bind()` (without significant inconvenience), it's better to just use a variable.